# Return path to images without image name

Tags: shell, terminal

I am using the following command to find my images in subfolders

```
find dk -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.jpeg' -type d > dk/files.csv
```

This however returns the subdirectories and also the image file name. I would like to return only the directories path to the images without the file name

I already tried with `find . -type d > folders.csv` but this gives me a list of all folders and not only the ones that contains an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.jpeg' \) \
-type f -exec dirname {} \+ | sort | uniq > folders.csv
```

How this works:

It does your `find` command, then pipes all the files to `dirname` which returns just the path to the file, not the file itself. We need both `sort` and `uniq` to get the unique directories (otherwise there'd be a duplicate for each image file a folder holds) and then we can go back to writing to your files.csv

Comment: I'd use `-exec dirname {} +` to reduce the number of times we need to invoke dirname.

Comment: Thank you however I get an empty file as a result

Comment: Unfortunately still not. It creates the file folders.csv but it is still empty.

Comment: @user3358102, fixed. needed  the parentheses around your `or` statements. Not sure why you didn't need them initially. tested and verified.